# Check for a multiple amount of information in a database

Tags: php, mysql

For my registration system, when the user registers, I want to make sure that their username, email, etc. is not taken. I have the code to check to see if the username exists, and I can probably do the same with the other stuff.

How can I do this without rewriting the block multiple times?

**tl;dr:** How can I check for more things in a database in a compact way?

```
$userquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($userquery)) {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        die ("Username Already Exists.");
    }
}
```

Comment: use function and call this function with argument

Comment: @JunaidAhmed I really like that idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an 'OR' condition in your where clause

```
$userquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email= '$email'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($userquery)) {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        die ("Username/Email Already Exists.");
    }
}
```

EDIT

ok then,

```
function doesitexist($mysqli,$table,$field,$value) {
    $userquery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = '$value' LIMIT 1";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($userquery)) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return('Error running Query');
    }

}
```

ANOTHER EDIT just for fun.  This should take an array of fields and values to check in one call.

```
$check = doesitexist($mysqli,'users',array('username'=>'bob','email'=>'someone@example.com'));

function doesitexist($mysqli,$table,$tocheck = array()) {

    if (count($tocheck)>0) {
        $where = '';
        foreach ($tocheck as $field=>$value) {
            $where .= $field." = '".addslashes($value)."' OR "; 
        }
        $where = trim($where," OR ");
        $userquery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where LIMIT 1";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($userquery)) {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return('Error running Query');
        }
    } else {
        return("No Fields/Values to check");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I like the idea of using a function for this.